# How to glue back a piece of wood (particle board) that fell from my kitchen cupboard?

Tags: adhesive, wooden-furniture, particle-board

As seen in the attached images, a piece of wood fell my from my kitchen cupboard, leaving behind a trace of something that looks like a red dried glue. (I don't have much experience with DIY and have no idea what kind of glue this is.)

What do you recommend I should do to glue back the piece? Should I try first to scrape out the red glue? The glue seems to have been very coarsely applied and some areas have noticeable bumps. It also seems very firmly glued to the cupboard.

Moreover, what kind/product of glue do you recommend me to use? I fear that some wood glues wouldn't work in this situation, as the glue has to be applied vertically. Moreover, the bumps of the red glue might make it difficult for the piece to connect back with the cupboard.

Many thanks!

[image: Cupboard with piece of wood by the side.]
[image: Another angle.]

Comment: is it a piece of wood, or a thin piece of veneer (less than 1/16" thick) that fell off?

Comment: A piece of wood around 2cm thick and 90cm tall.

Answer (score 1):

Well, all that glue did was to stick itself to the cupboard. There was not much in contact with the bit that fell off. So make sure of good contact next time.

Comment: In that case, the best course is to try to remove the red glue? What tool would you suggest for this job? Thanks!

Comment: @BrunoP.C. Why bother, it did not contact before...

Comment: I didn't put this red glue there -- it was there before me. How can I contact the bit that fell off with the cupboard if the red glue is on the way?